# Magic System Based on Electronics

Tags: science-based, magic, electricity

Lets assume mana as electrons . We have current, voltage, and resistance of a mana. Current is the flow of mana in our body, voltage as the force to make mana flowing in our body, and resistance to mana flow.

We can control our mana with some sort of ”mental” electronic components in our body. Resistor can be used to limit your mana, so that you dont exceed your mana ratings. Capacitor can be used to store your mana (it also can be used as filter), etc.

I was wondering what would be the magic counterpart to all subfield of electronics. I can think of power electronics as the ”strength build”, digital electronics as a magic controller for spells, etc.
Any feedback is appreciated.

Edit:
The magic system doesnt USE electronics, but it is a counterpart of electronics. It uses ”magic circuits” to conduct spells. Since my question is a bit too general, ill be a little more specific:

1. What would be the magic class (strength, healing, etc.) counterpart of the electronics subfields? Specifically power, digital, analog, and RF electronics.
2. What would happen if mana can be AC or DC? What spells can be conducted using those 2 types of current?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It depends a lot on the details of this electronic implant. Note also, most electric processes are far too fast to regulate by our brain. For example, low quality sound transfer requires already voltage change about 8000 times in a second. We can not do that, but we can give some meta-information to our electronics implant to do.

Comment: Hello @SmartWallet3000. Should you take the time to read through our [tour] and the following two Help Center pages ([help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]), you'll discover that your question needs to be more specific for this site. Brainstorming is discouraged on Stack Exchange, which wants to focus on specific problems with a single best answer. To be honest, 99% of your question would be answered with a basic study of electronics - but if you don't have the background yourself, then you're asking us to build the entire magic system for you, which we do not do.

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully its more specific

Comment: It seems to me that you're looking for a set of metaphors, this seems to me to be a writing issue - not a worldbuilding problem that we can solve. Could you clarify what the worldbuilding problem is?

Comment: @SmartWallet3000 it is still hard to figure out what you want with AC and DC. And i don't really know what the 1. Question is about as electricity can hardly be copied over to magic.

Answer (score 1):

- Generator: produces mana at a constant rate. The mana produced has too little voltage to be used for spells.
- Capacitor: stores mana, and outputs it at a high voltage and current for spells.
- Variable resistor: limits the mana coming out of the capacitor. Lets you control the strength of your spells.
- Motor: increases your body's speed and strength
- Radio: allows for telepathic communication
- Projector: allows for illusion magic
- Heater: produces heat
- Freezer: reduces heat (or moves it, if you prefer)
- Radar: detection magic
- Laser: light magic
- Magnetic fields: telekinesis
- Robots: golems
- Photovoltaic: absorbs sunlight and turns it into mana